# mutate_at in R with lambda function?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, scaling

I have a dataframe with 100 columns. Each column represent a probability value.

I want to do scaling there and I am using the following transformation:

```
df <- df %>%
      mutate_at(vars(specific_columns), 
                funs(function(x) {((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))}))
```

But it doesn't work and doesn't produce the output I want.

For example the sample data is:

```
col1        col2        col3        col4        col5        
0.014492754 0.014492754 0.014492754 0.014492754 0.014492754 
0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 
0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 
0.028985507 0.028985507 0.028985507 0.028985507 0.028985507 
0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 
0.014492754 0.014492754 0.014492754 0.014492754 0.014492754 
0.014492754 0.014492754 0.014492754 0.014492754 0.014492754 
0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 
0.010989011 0.010989011 0.010989011 0.010989011 0.010989011 
0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
```

Error:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Column `col1` is of unsupported
>   type function

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this syntax instead:

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate_at(vars(everything()), funs(((. - min(.)) / (max(.) - min(.)))))
#>         col1      col2      col3      col4      col5
#> 1  0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000
#> 2  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> 3  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> 4  1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
#> 5  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> 6  0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000
#> 7  0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000 0.5000000
#> 8  0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
#> 9  0.3791209 0.3791209 0.3791209 0.3791209 0.3791209
#> 10 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
```

`funs()` will *interpret* a pseudo-function for you. It helps deal with two cases which would not otherwise work:

1. Character name of a function (eg. "mean")
2. A call to a function with . as a dummy argument (as in my example)

If you have already declared your own (anonymous) function, there is no need to use `funs()` since `mutate_at()` will accept this as-is:

```r
mutate_at(df, vars(everything()), function(x) {((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))})
```

or

```r
my_func <- function(x) {((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))}
mutate_at(df, vars(everything()), my_func)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have done by playing myself. Thanks a lot.
But the real question why lambda function didn't work?

Comment: Oh sorry! I've updated the answer to explain that further :)